# What’s the best practice to handle multiple environments for one app?

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane, xcconfig

I'd like to know what is the best practice to have multiple apps for my app in multiple environments? I see some engineers use targets and other use xcconfig files to change the value of bundle identifier, app name, code signing certificates and so on?

So what do you thinks? 
For me, I use the second one with using Fastlane. any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables to use fastlane with multiple environment, see the [official instructions](https://docs.fastlane.tools/faqs/#multiple-targets-of-the-same-underlying-app).

Comment: This is a comment as it's currently written, not an answer. You should either include an excerpt from that external link in your post, or delete this and make it a comment to the question. If the link is unavailable for some reason, your answer has no useful content.